# using and overloading a template member function of a base class?

Tags: c++, overloading, template-function, using-declaration, member-functions

In the following, struct `Y` overloads `X`'s member function `f`. Both overloads are template functions, but take different arguments (`typename` and `int`), to be explicitly specified:

```
struct X
{
    template <typename> static bool f() { return true; }
};

struct Y : public X
{
    using X::f;
    template <int> static bool f() { return false; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Y::f <void>() << " " << Y::f <0>() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `1 0` using gcc, as expected. However, clang (3.3) complains that

```
[...] error: no matching function for call to 'f'
        std::cout << Y::f <void>() << " " << Y::f <0>() << std::endl;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
[...] note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument
      for 1st template parameter
        template <int> static bool f() { return false; }
                                   ^
```

i.e., can only see `Y`'s version. I've tried

```
using X::template f;
```

instead, with no success. The same happens for non-static (template) member functions. So is this a bug?

Comment: interesting template in X

Comment: Note: I tried another version where template arguments are automatically deduced, and works in both compilers (but I need explicit specification in my case).

Comment: @iavr: on another note, the way you define main() is not portable.

Comment: @thokra How so? C++ compiler is required to insert `return 0;` by the Standard if programmer omits a return statement from `main()`.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: what about the args list?

Comment: @thokra It can be `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)` or `int main(int, char *[])`. All three are legal in C++.

Comment: Sorry about this, but my focus was above `main`, where the problem actually lies.

Comment: @iavr: don't sweat it, Petr is right. You're fine.

Comment: @iavr: do you absolutely need to inherit from X?

Comment: Yes. This is part of a much larger project: I am building tuples supporting syntax like `t._()` (access element, if single), `t._<3>` (element 3), `t._<sz <3,5,2> >()` (indirect tuple view referring to elements 3,5,2 of underlying tuple `t`) and so on. The method in question is `_()` and some class hierarchy is definitely needed if the code is to be elegant and maintainable.

Answer (score 6):

This conundrum was recently explained to me in the light of another answer.

From the #clang IRC channel:

```
[01:16:23] <zygoloid> Xeo: this is a weird corner of the language where clang conforms but the rule is silly
[01:16:31] <Xeo> ... really? :(
[01:16:45] <zygoloid> Xeo: when deciding whether a using-declaration is hidden, we're not allowed to look at the template-parameter-list (nor the return type, iirc)
[01:17:04] <zygoloid> so the derived class declaration of operator()(T) suppresses the using-declaration
[01:17:19] <Xeo> because it has the same signature / parameter types?
[01:17:40] <zygoloid> rigth
```

The workaround is to **not** define `f` in the class that `uses` the derived version. Instead, move it into an auxiliary helper class (which, in this case begs the question, which definition you reckon should win).

- See here for my earlier problematic case: [Lambda functions as base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432260/lambda-functions-as-base-classes/18432618#18432618)

  > [@Xeo any idea why clang++ refuses this:
  > coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a0e6a1cac062216 (clang:
  > coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c2d6dd449a92227)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11737875#11737875)
- And here how to fix it using an extra base-class:

  > [@Xeo fixed it anyways, for some reason this form is not objectionable to clang++ stackoverflow.com/a/18432618/85371](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11738258#11738258)

**Credits** Thanks to @Xeo and people in the [Lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=11738957#11738957) for unearthing this "silly rule"

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it's bad news. Could you be a bit more specific on the workaround? Do you mean [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432260/lambda-functions-as-base-classes/18432618#18432618) involving lambdas? Because I need explicitly specified template arguments and I don't see how that fits.

Comment: @iavr I can't possibly tell, because in your case the function templates completely shadow each other. You should probably mask a subset of overloads using SFINAE so "the other" inherited template can kick in. Be sure to make the SFINAE branches non-overlapping, or you'll end up with ambiguous calls to `f` or (best case)

Comment: There is no possible condition to check with SFINAE, as far as I can see. Both overloads are equally valid and expected to be specified by the caller.

Comment: @iavr then, wouldn't you _by definition_ need to disambiguate? Use different function names, add a `tag` template argument, the works? I'm going to head over to your self-answer now, hadn't seen it earlier

Comment: @sehe disambiguation follows by explicitly specifying the template arguments by the caller (e.g. `f <void>()` vs `f <0>()`).

Comment: @sehe Note: `void` is a `typename`, `0` is `int` (non-type).

Answer (score 2):

It comes as a huge disappointment that such a constraint exists and has not been relaxed in C++11 (there may be good reason but I cannot imagine why). I feel like it defeats the whole concept of class hierarchies.

Anyhow, here's one workaround I have found. I have included another function `g` that is non-static to illustrate the differences, because this case is my main interest.

```
template <typename Y>
struct X
{
    template <typename> static bool f() { return true; }
    template <typename>        bool g() { return true; }

    template <int I>
    static bool f() { return Y::template _f <I>(); }

    template <int I>
    bool g()
    {
        return static_cast <Y&>(*this).template _g <I>();
    }
};

class Y : public X <Y>
{
    friend class X <Y>;
    template <int> static bool _f() { return false; }
    template <int>        bool _g() { return false; }
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    std::cout << Y::f <void>() << " " << Y::f <0>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << y. g <void>() << " " << y. g <0>() << std::endl;
}
```

So all overloading takes place in base class `X`, which implements static polymorphism by taking `Y` as a template argument (fortunately, this was already the case in my project so I do not change the design).

The actual `Y`'s implementations are in private functions `_f`, `_g`. This design is good when there are many derived classes like `Y` with only one overload in each, and a single base class `X` with multiple other overloads. In this case, massive code duplication is avoided. Again, this is the case in my project.

`X` does not need to know the return value of these functions. Unfortunately, it does need to know the return type: I have tried e.g. `auto g() -> decltype(...)` and again this `decltype` only works in gcc. Enabling c++1y one only writes `auto g()` without the trailing return type specification, thus avoiding the problem with `decltype`. However, [clang's support](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) for "return type deduction for normal functions" ([N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html)) is only available in current SVN version.

Until `auto g()` becomes mainstream (and standard), one has to compute the return type of `Y`'s methods by hand, which may be painful especially if there are lots of `Y`s.

It still looks like a mess to me, but at least not a complete one.